# How do I get local mtime from fstat in perl?

Tags: perl, strftime

Is it possible to get/convert the mtime from fstat to local time in perl?

If I do

```
my $stat = stat($file);
my $mtime = $stat->mtime;
my $time = Time::Piece->strptime($time, '%s');
```

and then format that time to - say - `'%Y%m%d%H%M'` I get a time that's 1 hour earlier than the time I see on `ls -l`, as I live in and my machine is configured to GMT+1.

I would instead like to have an output that's consistent with `ls -l`

so that if

```
> ls -l foo.txt
> -rw-r--r--@  1 somuser  296108113    163673 Mar 31 16:43 foo.txt
```

the output is `202003311643`instead of - like I get now - `202003311443` (GMT+1 and DST).

Is there a way to handle this in a straightforward way (i.e.: so that I don't have to manually adjust for the timezone, or DST)?

Comment: Try setting the "TZ" environment variable.  Not in Perl, but in your shell or whatever.  LONG ago, you used to always need this, not sure it's true anymore, but I always set it on every machine I use anyways.  For me (eastern US), it's TZ=EST5EDT, so look for a format like that that applies to where you are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Time::Piece object can represent either  a local time or a UTC time. The following creates an object representing a UTC time:

```
my $time = Time::Piece->strptime($mtime, '%s');
```

The equivalent for creating a local time is

```
use Time::Piece;
my $time = localtime->strptime($mtime, '%s');
```

or

```
my $time = Time::Piece::localtime->strptime($mtime, '%s');
```

That said, using `strptime` is unnecessary here. One can simply use

```
use Time::Piece;
my $time = localtime($mtime);
```

or

```
my $time = Time::Piece::localtime($mtime);
```

to get the correct Time::Piece object.

Comment: thanks that kind of works. I do get the local time, now I just have to figure how to output it correctly.